# How to trigger schema methods multiple times correctly with mongoose

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mongoose, promise

I'm trying to trigger a user method twice but mongoose is complaining about saving in paralell:

`ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel`

The `awaitPromises`-array has two of the same methods inside of it that I thought would go smoothly with a `await Promise.all()`. Unfortunately it's not possible to add up the value beforehand to just run the method once.

Long story short: How do I trigger the same user method twice without running into a `.save()`-issue?

```
// User.js (Model)

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    account: {
        username: String,
        discordId: String
    },
    stats: {
        attack: 50
    },
    hero: {
        rank: 0,
        currentHealth: 100
    }

userSchema.methods.loseHp = function(damage) {
    this.hero.currentHealth -= damage
    if (this.hero.currentHealth <= 0) {
        this.hero.currentHealth = 1
    }
    return this.save();
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

```
// gameLogic.js
const calculateResult = async (player, enemy)=>{
    const awaitPromises = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < enemy.allowedAttacks; i += 1) { // max 3 iterations
        awaitPromises.push(player.loseHp(Math.random()*enemy.stats.attack))
        }
    
    try {
        await Promise.all(awaitPromises)
    } catch(error){
        console.log('error: ', error)
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should not `save()` after each attack, but only once after all the `loseHp` calls. Then you won't need `Promise.all` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A promise starts executing immediately, all that `Promise.all` does is return a promise that fulfills when all of the passed in promises fulfill (but at that time they might have already fulfilled!). If Mongoose doesn't like two promises for the same model in flight, you might need to execute them one by one within the loop:

```
await player.loseHp(Math.random()*enemy.stats.attack);
```

2. Why do you call `loseHp` multiple times? Couldn't you just add up the damage and call `loseHp` once at the end?